# Infinite urls with underscores and timestamps

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Some posts I searched suggests the problem resides in ajax handled by jquery. I tested by removing all ajax calls and following what other posts have suggested by using $ajaxSetup({cache:true}) and other methods but none of them works. I also tried remove either the jquery library or my script completely. And the infinite loop of get requests stopped.

The problem seems to reside in this piece of code where all_posts[j][0] is a div element re-inserted into the document. I tried placing alert(j) before and after the line of append. When placing before, the value alerted is as expected in a loop, from 0 to 6 and started again due to infinite loop of get requests. But when placed after, the only thing alerted is 0

```
for (var j = 0; j < all_posts.length; j++){
        if (all_posts[j][3]){

            $(".container").append(all_posts[j][0]);
        }

    }
```

Below is the server log:

```
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:02]"GET /static/jquery.js?_=1446705842818 HTTP/1.1" 200 284394
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:02]"GET /static/ui/dist/js/vendor/video.js?_=1446705842819 HTTP/1.1" 200 66306
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/ui/dist/js/flat-ui-pro.js?_=1446705842820 HTTP/1.1" 200 1031693
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/jq-cookie/jquery.cookie.js?_=1446705842821 HTTP/1.1" 200 3121
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/top_js/myads.js?_=1446705842822 HTTP/1.1" 200 9521
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/jquery.js?_=1446705842964 HTTP/1.1" 200 284394
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/ui/dist/js/vendor/video.js?_=1446705842965 HTTP/1.1" 200 66306
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/ui/dist/js/flat-ui-pro.js?_=1446705842966 HTTP/1.1" 200 1031693
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/jq-cookie/jquery.cookie.js?_=1446705842967 HTTP/1.1" 200 3121
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/top_js/myads.js?_=1446705842968 HTTP/1.1" 200 9521
[05/Nov/2015 06:44:03]"GET /static/jquery.js?_=1446705843169 HTTP/1.1" 200 284394
```

Constantly requesting static scripts.
I use Django and its development server.
The html snippet being appended to is:

```
<div class="row post">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
        <div class="my-post-item">
            <div class="my-post-item-inner">
                <div class="my-post-item-inner-inner">
                    <div class="my-post-title">
                        <a href="#"><h4>{{post.title_line}}</h4></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-post-description">
                        <p>{{post.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-post-tags">
                        Tags:
                        {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                            <span class="label label-warning">{{tag.text}}</span>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-post-control button-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-secondary btn-xs btn-embossed">Edit</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-default btn-secondary btn-xs btn-embossed comments-button">Comments</button>
                        {% if post.shown %}
                            <button class="btn btn-warning btn-secondary btn-xs post-hide-button btn-embossed">Hide from Public</button>
                        {% else %}
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-secondary btn-xs post-show-button btn-embossed">Show for Public</button>
                        {% endif %}
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-secondary btn-xs post-delete-button btn-embossed">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="my-post-info row">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 first-info-child">
                            <p class="first-post-time"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p class="last-modified-time"></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <p>Posted by: <br>{{post.poster.user_profile.first_name}} {{post.poster.user_profile.last_name}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-id-info">
                        {{post.id}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-bg-img-info">
                        {{post.images.all.0.file.name}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="hidden-sorting-info" style="display: none">
                        <p class="last-modified-stamp">{{post.last_updated|date:"U"}}</p>
                        <p class="post-date-stamp">{{post.post_time|date:"U"}}</p>
                    <div class="hidden-popover-content" style="display: none">yap</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What *is* the error exactly?

Comment: Scripts keep the browser sending requests to get static script files. Never stopping as the server log I pasted. Every request url has the paramter ?_=some timestamp. @Sayse

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I find the problem. Just in case somebody who might be encountering the same problem without knowing what exactly is the cause. I missed a closing div tag on my html file. This makes the script tag be inside the div tag with class post. Every time append is run, the script tag is inserted into the document. The browser will try to access this script without stopping.

I understand why there is an infinite loop but I don't get it why jquery will think it is a cached copy and other scripts are also reloaded.